# Не получается выставить куки из page.eavluate в PhantomJS

Tags: cookie, phantomjs, page

Есть два сервера: site1.com и site2.com

первый выставляет куки, все гуд, но когда пытаюсь динамически создать script in phantom.evaluate и в качестве юрл указать site2.com то все обламывается.
сервер site2.com шлет заголовки, что нужно поставить куки, но phantomjs не понимает.

```
 page.open("http://site1.com", function(){
          page.evaluate(function(){
            var d = document.createElement('script');
            d.src = "http://site2.com/javascript_file.js"
            document.appendChild(d);
          });
        });
```

Что делать? Как бытЬ?

Answer (score 1):

В PhantomJS есть метод, внедряющий внешний js-файл в код страницы. Используйте page.includeJs.

Пример из [официальной документации](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/include-js.html):

```
page.includeJs('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js', function() {
  // jQuery is loaded, now manipulate the DOM
  var $loginForm = $('form#login');
  $loginForm.find('input[name="username"]').value('phantomjs');
  $loginForm.find('input[name="password"]').value('c45p3r');
});
```